# How to view local site on mobile?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have a windows 7 laptop and a phone, both connected to my home wifi network. I have a local site running on my IIS7 windows laptop. If I type localhost, I can see the default page.

The problem is that now I want to view that page on my phone. How can I get to it?

I tried

localhost:81

I tried getting my public ip, then putting :81 after, and it didn't work.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You need the internal IP of the machine (within the same network)

Comment: How can I get the internal IP?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask on [su]

Comment: From `ipconfig` or the properties of the network adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public IP address allows computers on the internet to connect to your router.
It won't work inside your local network.

You need to connect to the internal IP address of the computer itself – the one belonging to the network adapter connecting it to the router.
You can get this address from the `ipconfig` command, or the properties of the network adapter.

Comment: I got the address `http://192.168.1.101:81/site/` and it works on my browser on the laptop, but when I try on my phone it takes a while, then says page not available.